# How to handle custom radio buttons

Tags: ios, swift, button, radio-button

Hi I need to radio button in my project like
[Radio Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko3R9.png)
I take images into button, Booth selected and empty.
How to I can handle these one is selected another one is don't select.
our selection is only once.

```
@IBOutlet var nothisonlybtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var biweeklybtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var weeklybtn: UIButton!
```

How to we are handle by using of button outlets

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton

Comment: you only need to check if the button checked or not !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are giving one common action for all buttons and give those Tags like 0,1,2.

Try with this code.

```
@IBAction func radioButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        weeklybtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Radio Button"), for: .normal)
        biweeklybtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Radio Button"), for: .normal)
        nothisonlybtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Radio Button"), for: .normal)
        weeklylbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 112/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1.0)
        biweeklylbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 92/225, green: 112/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1.0)
        onlyForthisLbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 92/225, green: 112/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1.0)
        if sender.tag == 0
        {
            weeklybtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked"), for: .normal)
            weeklylbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 125/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        else if sender.tag == 1
        {
            biweeklybtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked"), for: .normal)
            biweeklylbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 125/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        else
        {
            nothisonlybtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked"), for: .normal)
            onlyForthisLbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 125/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The image you've posted shows a table view will do good in this case.

If so, use the tableView `tableView: didSelectItemAt indexPath:` & `tableView tableView: didDeselectItemAt indexPath:` methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! <#UITableViewCellClass#>
    cell.rImageBtn.setImage(<#selected image#>, for: .normal)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! <#UITableViewCellClass#>
    cell.rImageBtn.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
}
```

And if the images are individual entities in a UIView, then:

```
@IBOutlet weak var rImageBtn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var rImageBtn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var rImageBtn3: UIButton!

@objc func button1Tapped() {
    rImageBtn1.setImage(<#selected image#>, for: .normal)
    rImageBtn2.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
    rImageBtn3.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
}

@objc func button2Tapped() {
    rImageBtn1.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
    rImageBtn2.setImage(<#selected image#>, for: .normal)
    rImageBtn3.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
}

@objc func button3Tapped() {
    rImageBtn1.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
    rImageBtn2.setImage(<#unselected image#>, for: .normal)
    rImageBtn3.setImage(<#selected image#>, for: .normal)
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: No it is not working I don't use the tableview I take those as a buttons in a view. we select one button automatically selected button image also changed no need to again select for DeselectItem.

Comment: If you try the second snippet, I hope it will work. It doesn’t need a tableview nor selecting twice. Once a button is selected, the others will be deselected **automatically**.

Comment: Sorry we are no need to write the superate actions for every button, we will write that one with single action.
Once observe my code Bellow

Answer (score 0):

Give one common `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` for all buttons and give those Tags like 0,1,2.

[image]

**Common IBOutlet**

```
@IBOutlet var radioButtons: [UIButton]!
```

**Common IBAction**

```
@IBAction func radioButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

   for button in radioButtons {
        if button.tag == sender.tag {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked"), for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 46/225, green: 125/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }else{
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Radio Button"), for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 112/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }

}
```